# What am I missing in my RegEx expression?

Tags: html, regex

So, regex has been the bane of my existence for some time. I feel that I'm on the cusp of understanding it, but I'm just getting very frustrated. In short:

I'm attempting to scrape data from the following website via PHP:

http://magicseaweed.com/Asbury-Park-Surf-Report/857/

I want to extract the bold wave height at the top of the page (at the moment, it reads 3-5). I understand why this works:

```
preg_match('/<div class="msw-fct-ccd msw-sr-details span3"> <h3> <span>(.*)    
<small>ft<\/small>   <\/span> <div class="msw-fct-ccr msw-sr-rating">/', $pageMagic,
$height);
```

But I don't understand why this will not:

```
preg_match('/<div class="msw-fct-ccd msw-sr-details span3"> <h3> <span>(/d-/d)|(/d)    
<small>ft<\/small>   <\/span> <div class="msw-fct-ccr msw-sr-rating">/', $pageMagic,
$height);
```

In my mind, logically speaking, it should be looking for a digit, a dash, then another digit OR just one digit. I tested out regex in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it picked up 3-5. Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 2):

Your slashes are the wrong way around. It should be:

```
(\d-\d)|(\d)
```

Incidentally, you can simplify this to:

```
\d(-\d)?
```

...but note that this would change the capture groups. I leave the fix for that as an exercise for you :)